# WiFi signal problem on Ubuntu 14.10 on USB

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, iwlwifi

Hi everyone I'm running

```
uname -a   
Linux ubuntu 3.16.0-23-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 21 17:56:17 UTC 2014 x86_64
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

on usb stick

My problem is that my wifi signal decreases very rapidly with distance, normally i surf the net with windows from my room, however on ubuntu the signal is very low.

I tried to solve by using

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```

but i get this error

```
rmmod: ERROR: missing module name.
modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi
```

tried to fix by changing

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

and adding the line

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

but still hasnt worked

I'm adding more information about my system below

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE 
Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
```

iwconfig near

```
iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:""  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point:    
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-28 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:332   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

iwconfig far (dont know if it helps)

```
iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:""  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point:    
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:13   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

iwlwifi.conf

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

ask me for more infos if needed and sorry for bad english.

Comment: As you don't have an Intel card that uses the driver iwlwifi, your changes to iwlwifi.conf will be ineffective.

Comment: that makes very sense haha but how do I upgrade drivers for my card then?

Answer (score 1):

Your Realtek card uses the driver rtl8188ee. There are a few driver parameters you might try. First:

```
sudo -i
rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188ee.conf
echo "options rtl8188ee msi=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188ee.conf
modprobe -r rtl8188ee
modprobe rtl8188ee
exit
```

Any improvement? If there is no improvement, please also try a reboot.

Aside from the change in reported link quality, what are your symptoms?

Comment: This didnt work, instead now it simply doesnt connect. Finds the connections but fails to connect.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. However, please mention that everyone has different realtek driver number. So, first do "lspci -nn | grep 0280" and whatever "RTL..." number is given, above script will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but for whoever is helps -
@chilli555's solution works perfectly, however for me i had to do one additional step (disabling intel driver) before it worked perfectly for me -

```
driver=$(lspci -nn | grep 0280 | awk '{print tolower($9)}')

rm /etc/modprobe.d/$driver.conf
echo "options $driver msi=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/$driver.conf
modprobe -r $driver
modprobe $driver

rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
echo "options iwlwifi 11en_disable=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

Write above script in a file and run this executable.

Restart the system

Comment: This does not work for me. The command `lspci -nn | grep 0280`  returns `03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
` and the `driver` variable becomes `wireless`

Comment: I ended up throwing that laptop and buying a new one. There were other problems in my system that started a few days after I fixed my wifi using above approach.