# Slow WiFi connection on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, connection

I am new to Ubuntu and after I installed Ubuntu on my PC, I am experiencing a terribly slow WiFi connection (but faster on Windows). I tried to disable the 802.11n and the Intel driver card but it gives me the following error (running `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi`):

```
rmmod: ERROR: missing module name.
modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi
```

I also tried following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560377/wifi-signal-problem-on-ubuntu-14-10-on-usb) but `lspci -nn | grep 0280` returns nothing on my Terminal.

When running `lspci -knn | grep -i net` it returns:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM-3 
Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10de] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection [1028:027f]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: ```lspci -knn | grep -i net``` command don't shown wireless interface, try to find your hardware type by other way.

Comment: would you mind telling me how? thank you

Comment: Try the next command ```lspci -knn | grep -i Wireless```
And try also command without ```grep```, only ```lspci -knn``` and find someting with words *network* and *wireless*

Comment: Are you using a USB adapter?

Answer (score 0):

For those coming across this still, check your kernel version with `uname -a`. If the version is 5.1 or greater, it should support your hardware without needing the iwlwifi driver.

Remove the iwlwifi driver (***cautiously if you don't have an ethernet backup***):

1. `apt search ilwwifi`. You should see something like:

```
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
backport-iwlwifi-dkms/focal,focal 8324-0ubuntu1 all iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format

oem-wifi-iwlwifi-mainline-5.1rc1-dkms/now 6 amd64 [residual-config] (none)
```

2. Remove each that is installed on your machine. For example `apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms oem-wifi-iwlwifi-mainline-5.1rc1-dkms`
3. Reboot if needed.